# Does a request to Amplify-Cognito bypass Angular HTTP interceptors

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito, angular8, angular-http-interceptors

stack:Angular 8; AWS-Cognito

I am using Cognito for user authentication. I also have an interceptor that attach a token to all API request going out of my app and catch all responses errors back from sever.

I want to use the status code from server response (200) for the Cognito request. According to AWS the successful response for `Auth.forgotPassword`

> If the action is successful, the service sends back an HTTP 200 response.
>   The following data is returned in JSON format by the service.
>   CodeDeliveryDetails

and I want to use a response code not the JSON, from Cognito to check if the submission was successful.

But it seems all request done to Cognito Identity Provider never use the angular http client or is bypassing the angular interceptor. All API's request have the token attached but none of the request to Cognito have any token.

Even more If I take away the HttpClientModule from angular there are still Cognito http request

Where is that residing and How do I catch that full response? , not just the JSON but the headers as well

Comment: Buddy, I'm with the same problem today. Manage to solve or at least understand?